# not able to open link on index page

Tags: java, filter

On my index page with userid and password i have also given a link to forgotten password jsp page but i am not able to open it . On clicking the link it stays on the index page.

My AuthenticationFilter is-

```
package bean;

import java.io.IOException; 
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {private ServletContext context;

    @Override
public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
    this.context = fConfig.getServletContext();
    this.context.log("AuthenticationFilter initialized");
}

    @Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

            res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
            res.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
            res.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.

    String uri = req.getRequestURI();
    this.context.log("Requested Resource::"+uri);

    HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
```

After adding uri.endsWith("jsp") in the below if condition it started working could someone explain why is it working now and why it was not working when uri.endsWith("jsp") was not there.

```
    if(session == null && !(uri.endsWith("html") || uri.endsWith("LoginServlet")|| uri.endsWith("jsp"))){
        this.context.log("Unauthorized access request");
        res.sendRedirect("index.html");
    }else{
        // pass the request along the filter chain
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }


}
    @Override
public void destroy() {
    //close any resources here
}

}
```

Comment: Does your filter run in that case? And if it does, did you debug it?

Comment: it runs but i did not debug it.

Comment: Then do that, you're better suited to step through your code and see what it does. My guess would be that `session` is null but as I said it's a guess. Only you can tell us what is going on there.

Comment: session gets created on submitting userid and password

Comment: However, the question is: has the session already been created when the filter is running? And since you seems to have the problem with "forgot password" there is no submitting userid and password (at least not necessarily). In any case you should fire up a debugger and step through your code to see which decisions are made and why (e.g. a redirect to the index page is probably caused by this condition : `session == null && !(uri.endsWith("html") || uri.endsWith("LoginServlet"))` and you should check which part makes it succeed).